# Super keyword doesn't work with variables when trying to extend p5.js library

Tags: angularjs, typescript, p5.js

I want to extend the p5.js library in order to have error text on various locations on the screen. I will be using it in different places throughout my app and I believe it's better to do this than duplicating the code.

For now, almost everything is working fine, except some properties. For example, if I access `super.height` I'll get 0, while if I access `this.height` I'll get the actual window height. But, when accessing `this.height` I get an error saying that `height` isn't defined in CustomP5, which is right, but at the same time confusing.

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';

export class CustomP5 extends p5 {
  ... // private fields not related to this issue
  constructor(sketch, htmlElement) {
    super(sketch, htmlElement);

    // Set tooltip error variables
    this.resetTooltipError();
  }

  setSetup(setupFunction) {
    super.setup = () => {
      setupFunction();
      this.setupAdditional();
    }
  }

  setDraw(drawFunction) {
    super.draw = () => {
      drawFunction();
      this.drawAdditional();
    };
  }

  showTooltipError() {
    ...
  }
```

Is there a reason why `super.height`, `super.mouseX`, and `super.mouseY` don't work, while `super.draw` or `super.mousePressed` are working correctly?

PS: I'm quite new to js and ts, so be patient if I'm wrong, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but it sounds like `super` only works with functions, not variables.

You say it works with `super.draw` and `super.mousePressed`. These are both functions. You say it does not work with `super.height`, `super.mouseX`, or `super.mouseY`. All of these are variables.

This matches the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super) for super:

> The **super** keyword is used to access and call functions on an object's parent.
>
> ```
> class Rectangle {
>   constructor(height, width) {
>     this.name = 'Rectangle';
>     this.height = height;
>     this.width = width;
>   }
>   sayName() {
>     console.log('Hi, I am a ', this.name + '.');
>   }
>   get area() {
>     return this.height * this.width;
>   }
>   set area(value) {
>     this.height = this.width = Math.sqrt(value);
>   }
> }
>
> class Square extends Rectangle {
>   constructor(length) {
>     this.height; // ReferenceError, super needs to be called first!
>
>     // Here, it calls the parent class' constructor with lengths
>     // provided for the Rectangle's width and height
>     super(length, length);
>
>     // Note: In derived classes, super() must be called before you
>     // can use 'this'. Leaving this out will cause a reference error.
>     this.name = 'Square';
>   }
> }
> ```

So it sounds like this is working as intended. You might want to take some time to read up on how inheritance and the super keyword work in JavaScript.